# Street address regex for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, street-address

The rules for this test are:

1. Must contain letters and numbers
2. May contain these special characters anywhere within the string:

```
Number sign (#)
Minus (-)
Full stop (.)
Slash (/)
Space ( )
```

3. May **not** contain any other special characters
4. May **not** consist of only letters
5. May **not** consist of only letters and/or the special characters
6. May **not** consist of only numbers
7. May **not** consist of only numbers and/or the special characters
8. The numbers, letters and special characters may be in any order

Examples of desired matches:

```
445b
apt 445a
Apt. #445
Apt 445
Apt-445
Apt - 445
apt445
apt#445
apt/445
APT-445a
APT - 445c
Apt# 445b
Apt. #445-c
22 Elm St.
```

Examples of non-matches:

```
apt four forty five
Elm St.
Elm St
Elm Street
445
445 445
445-445
#445
(any or all of the special characters by themselves)
```

[41686d6564's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/41686d6564) answer below is extremely close but in my original question I failed to specify that spaces are part of the special characters:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/]+$/
```

I've tried on my own to get the space special character incorporated but I don't get the desired outcome.

See the live example.
[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/47c3iz/1)

Comment: Sorry, but *Must be a mix of alpha and numeric characters* and *May contain the special characters shown inside these parenthesis* are contradictory. So, the first requirement can be crossed out, right? Next, *The string may start with the special characters*, what about the end of string?

Comment: If both letters and digits must be present (even when special characters are used), and if the special characters can appear anywhere (you didn't state otherwise), you may use `^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9\-#.\/]+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/47c3iz/1)). If that's not what you need, you should [edit] the question and clarify the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex validates your rules:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/])/
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - positive lookahead for at least one alpa char
- `(?=.*\d)` - positive lookahead for at least one digit char
- `(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/])` - negative lookahead for any not allowed char

Instead of the double negative you could use a pattern looking for all valid chars until end of string:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/]*$/
```

UPDATE based on updated requirement to allow spaces:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/ ])/
```

Explanation: Simply add a space to the negated character class

Alternatively, look for all valid chars, including space:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/ ]*$/
```

UPDATE, with JavaScript tests:

```js
const tests = `445b
apt 445a
Apt. #445
Apt 445
Apt-445
Apt - 445
apt445
apt#445
apt/445
APT-445a
APT - 445c
Apt# 445b
Apt. #445-c
22 Elm St.
apt four forty five
Elm St.
Elm St
Elm Street
445
445 445
445-445
#445`;
var regex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9\-#\.\/ ])/;
tests.split(/[\r\n]+/).forEach((str) => {
  result = regex.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + result);
});
```

Comment: Peter, I updated the question as I forgot to specify that 'spaces' are part of the special characters allowed.  How does this effect your answer?  The second part of your answer is what I have currently.  When I add \s to the last section it basically allows almost anything to pass.

Comment: I added a JavaScript code snippet, now that you stated that you use JavaScript. In the future, please state your question with details so that we can help better.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm new to asking questions here and it took a minute to get the question just right.  Thank you for the thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to validate if a given string matches a set of password rules, right?  I suggest that you don't use a single regex.  Here's how I would write it in Perl, but this should be applicable to any language:

```
# Must be all letters, digits or some punctuation.
if ( $str =~ /^[-#./A-Za-z0-9]+$/ ) {
    $ok = 1;
}
else {
    $ok = 0;
}

# If it is entirely letters, it is bad.
if ( $str =~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/ ) {
    $ok = 0;
}

# If it is entirely digits, it is bad.
if ( $str =~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {
    $ok = 0;
}
```

That covers all your rules.  It is more lines of code than matching against one hard-to-read regex, but it's much easier for you to understand, and to modify in the future.

You're going to wrap that in a function called  something like`is_password_valid`, so it doesn't matter if it takes up 20 lines.

Comment: Thanks Andy I appreciate this very much.  Actually this is an address field and the rules are from another department in my company.  The form is a a semi-internal form so it's not really public facing.  I'm validating the field in JS but I can definitely adopt your Perl code to that.